# sitemesh + struts2 How to include external files in standard.jsp

Tags: struts2, sitemesh

My company has 20+ web applications. They all use Struts2 and Sitemesh to decorate the pages.

Every application has its own version of header.html and footer.html which are included in standard.jsp (using `<%@ include file=filename%>`).

For look and feel consistency across applications I want to have the header and footer files outside of the web application.

However I can't figure out how to do that!

My decorator.xml looks like this

```
<decorators defaultdir="/layout">
   <decorator name="standard-layout" page="standard.jsp">
      <pattern>/*</pattern>
   </decorator>
</decorators>
```

My include directive `<%@ include file="/common/header.html%>`, gets prefix with the defaultdir value, like this /layout/common/header.html, and I get a file not found error.

The same thing happens if I use an absolute path.

Also, the same thing happens if I change decorators.xml like this.

```
<decorators>
   <decorator name="standard-layout" page="/layout/standard.jsp">
      <pattern>/*</pattern>
   </decorator>
</decorators>
```

Help will be appreciated!

Update:  I was able to solve this using JSTL

```
<c:import var="commomHeader" url="/resources/html/common_header.html"/>
${commomHeader}
```

Comment: Do you want the header and footer files outside of the web application? Where do you want them?

Comment: In a specific directory in the application server. We are already setup to read some configuration files from outside of the application.

Comment: What are their files?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I should clarify that the other configuration files are read from the java classes not from the jsps.  The issue that I have is trying to read the footer or header from standard.jsp

Comment: Did this work for you? My jsp decorator seems to not work like a jsp. It works like html. Instead of including the files like this <%@include file="something.jsp" %>  it just prints it and does nothing. How do i import an html in my jsp decorator?